# How do I get associated records to show in active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, activeadmin, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a registration app which records a `Participant` model, which has two hanging models- `Student_Detail` and `Volunteer_Detail`. `Participant` `has_one` of `Student_Detail` and `Volunteer_Detail`.

There is a third model, `Group`. `Group` records which participants are matched to each other. Because Participant may be involved in more than one `Group` and a `Group` may have more than one `Participant`, I assume `has_and_belongs_to_many` is the best association for `Participant` and `Group`.

A join table exists for `Group` and `Participant`

I am newer to Rails and I am using active admin to manage this app.

When I login, I can see each model that I've generated as a resource, but I am hoping to be able to show associated details (Student/Volunteer/Group)of each participant when I view the `Participant` tab. Currently, it only shows attributes which are only for that specific model, not for any associated models.

Here is my active_admin resource code for the model `Participant`:

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Participant do

                            permit_params :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :email, :birthdate, :phone, 
                                              :street_name, :city, :state, :zip, :role, student_details_attributes: [:nationality, :religion, :need_ride, 
                                            :has_spouse, :spouse_name, :english_level, :expectation, :length_of_stay, :exact_length, :volunteer_id, 
                                            :matched, :returned_home, :participant_id], volunteer_details_attributes: [:date, :importance, :story, :questions, :participant_id]


                            end
```

I'd like to be able to view all attributes associated with an entry in the `Participant` table when I view it in Active Admin. Currently I only see attributes that are directly from that model (:first_name, :last_name, :gender, :email, :birthdate, :phone, :street_name, :city, :state, :zip, :role)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me try to guess, you need to display attributes of associations

```
show do |participant|
  attributes_table do
    row :id
    row :full_name
    attributes_table_for participant.volunteer_detail do
      row :id
      row :volunteer_name
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: should I put this in my dashboard.rb file, or my active_admin.rb file?

Comment: to app/admin/participant.rb